# Python, como calcular a média de uma lista de 5 em 5 elementos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho um problema em que preciso calcular a média de 5 em 5 elementos em uma lista, por exemplo, fazer a média dos 5 primeiros elementos, em seguida fazer a média dos próximos 5 elementos e assim por diante. Tentei usar fatiamento de listas `[::5]` mas isso só retorna o intervalo e não é o que eu quero. Vou deixar aqui um pequeno código como exemplo:

```
lista = [1,2,4,3,7,4,6,5,8,1,9,4,3] # Aqui seria calcular a média do 1 até o 7 depois do 4 até o 1 e assim em diante...     
media = sum(lista[::5]) / 5     
print(media)
```

Answer (score 4):

A sessão *"Itertools Recipes"* na [documentação do módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) contém um exemplo de uma função chamada `grouper` que faz o agrupamento de N em N elementos de um iterável (de maneira eficiente). Basta você calcular a média de cada grupo retornado dessa função.

Segue um exemplo usando o exemplo da documentação:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


lista = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 1, 9, 4, 3]

for grupo in grouper(lista, n=5):
    # Remove os `None` do último grupo
    grupo = [num for num in grupo if num is not None]

    media = sum(grupo) / len(grupo)

    print(f"Grupo: {grupo!r}")
    print(f"- Média: {media}")
```

Saída:

```
Grupo: [1, 2, 4, 3, 7]
- Média: 3.4
Grupo: [4, 6, 5, 8, 1]
- Média: 4.8
Grupo: [9, 4, 3]
- Média: 5.333333333333333
```

---

**Edit**

Estou usando list comprehension juntamente com `is not None`para remover os valores `None` do último grupo, pois se eu apenas testar se o número é falseável o código removeria os zeros da lista.

```
lista = [0, 1, 2, 3, None]

ok = [n for n in lista if n is not None]  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
wrong = [n for n in lista if n]  # [1, 2, 3]
wrong_too = list(filter(None, lista))  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Um for até o tamanho da lista com step 5
2. No segundo for preencher a lista de cinco elementos (lista5)
3. Calcular a soma da lista5 e dividir pelo tamanho para obter a média.

   ```
    lista = [1,2,4,3,7,4,6,5,8,1,9,4,3]
    media = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista), 5):
        lista5 = []
        for j in range(0, 5):
            if((i + j) < len(lista)):
                lista5.append(lista[i + j])
                print(str(lista[i + j]), end=' ')
        media.append(sum(lista5) / len(lista5))
        print()
    print(media)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade é criar uma [gerador](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/howto/functional.html#generators) que divida um iterável em porções e calcular individualmente as médias para essas porções.

```
lista = [1,2,4,3,7,4,6,5,8,1,9,4,3]

def chunk(iteravel, n):
    for i in range(0, len(iteravel), n):
        yield iteravel[i:i+n]

s = map(lambda e:sum(e)/len(e), chunk(lista, 5))


print(*s)    #3.4 4.8 5.333333333333333
```

<sup>Teste o código no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/JJ4MQC)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução com [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
lista = [1,2,4,3,7,4,6,5,8,1,9,4,3] 
r = 5
media = [sum(lista[i:i+r])/len(lista[i:i+r]) for i in range(0,len(lista),r)]
print(media)
```

Como mencionado [@fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6333/fernandosavio), podemos usar [o operador walrus](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), mas funciona com o python 3.8 e superior:

```py
media = [sum(l:=lista[i:i+r])/len(l) for i in range(0,len(lista),r)]
```

Saída:

```
[3.4, 4.8, 5.333333333333333]
```

Comment: A média do último grupo deveria ser `5.3333...` pois o último agrupamento tem apenas 3 elementos e não 5

Comment: Mas você consegue resolver usando walrus operator: `[sum(l:=lista[i:i+r])/len(l) for i in range(0,len(lista),r)]`. Vou deixar os [`docs`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) para os curiosos

Comment: @fernandosavio, Obrigado, atualizado!

Answer (score 1):

A partir do [**Python 3.12**](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html) (outubro de 2023) é possível usar a [função `itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched), que serve justamente para retornar pedaços de um iterável, um por vez.

Uma vantagem é que ela já trata o caso do último pedaço ser menor que o tamanho indicado, então basta iterar pelos pedaços e calcular a média de cada um:

```py
from itertools import batched

lista = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 1, 9, 4, 3]
for grupo in batched(lista, 5):
    media = sum(grupo) / len(grupo)
    print(f"Grupo: {grupo}")
    print(f"- Média: {media}")
```

Saída:

```
Grupo: (1, 2, 4, 3, 7)
- Média: 3.4
Grupo: (4, 6, 5, 8, 1)
- Média: 4.8
Grupo: (9, 4, 3)
- Média: 5.333333333333333
```

Não ficou claro se é somente para imprimir as médias, ou se precisa guardá-las (por exemplo, em uma lista). Mas aí não é difícil de adaptar.

Por exemplo, se quiser uma lista com as médias:

```py
from itertools import batched

lista = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 1, 9, 4, 3]
medias = [ sum(grupo) / len(grupo) for grupo in batched(lista, 5) ]
print(medias) # [3.4, 4.8, 5.333333333333333]
```

Ou ainda, uma lista de tuplas, na qual cada tupla contém a lista de notas e as respectivas médias:

```py
from itertools import batched

lista = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 1, 9, 4, 3]
medias = [ (list(grupo), sum(grupo) / len(grupo)) for grupo in batched(lista, 5) ]
print(medias) # [([1, 2, 4, 3, 7], 3.4), ([4, 6, 5, 8, 1], 4.8), ([9, 4, 3], 5.333333333333333)]

# para mostrar de forma mais organizada, seria algo assim
for notas, media in medias:
    print(f'notas={notas} - média={media}')
```