# Como detectar Start codon e Stop codon em uma sequência de nucleotídeos utilizando Python?

Tags: python, string, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou tentando resolver um exercício no qual foi solicitado uma função com um *start* e um *stop*, onde o *start* deve ocorrer quando encontrar `"ATG"` e o *stop* quando encontrar o `"TAA"`, `"TAG"`, `"TGA"`.

Com ajuda dos comentários, consegui ajeitar um pouco o código, porém o stop está limitado a somente ao que eu colocar no `s.find()`. Gostaria de ajuda para fazer ele procurar por um dos três *stop codons* proposto no exercício.

Segue o enunciado do exercício que gerou a pergunta:

> Faça uma função `contacodon` em Python que receba uma sequência de
> letras representando nucleotídeos (e.g., `A`, `C`, `G`, `T`), verifique se a
> sequência é válida (i.e. contém somente `A`s, `C`s, `G`s, e `T`s) e retorne
> com o número de ocorrências de cada codon contando a partir do start
> codon `"ATG"` até um dos stop codons, `"TAA"`, `"TAG"`, `"TGA"`

Exemplo de entrada:

```
contacodon("AGCGATCGAGATGAGCATCGCATCGCGGACTACCGCGCGCGCGCGCGGGAGATGAGCATCGACGACTCGACTAG")
```

Saída para a entrada acima:

```
{
'ATG': 1,
'AGC': 1,
'ATC': 1,
'GCA': 1,
'TCG': 1,
'CGG': 1,
'ACT': 1,
'ACC': 1,
'GCG': 2,
'CGC': 2,
'GGG': 1,
'AGA': 1,
'TGA': 1
}
```

Meu código:

```
def verificar (s):
    s = s.upper()
    for ent in s:
        if not ent in "ACGT":
                return False
    return True
   
while True:
    s = str(input("Entre com a seq: \n")).upper()
    if verificar(s):
        break
    print("Seq inválida")
  
count={}
for i in range(s.find('ATG'),s.rfind('TAA')+1,3):
    codon = s[i:i+3]
    if codon in count:
        count[codon] += 1
    else:
        count[codon] = 1
print('\n', count, '\n',)
```

Comment: Tem o enunciado completo do exercício. Pois a explicação é vaga.

Comment: A sequência que o enunciado passou como exemplo não tem um comprimento múltiplo de três. É isso mesmo? Se sim, a abordagem que você fez (de percorrer a string de três em três) não irá funcionar.

Comment: É um erro proposital, os codons que serão testados serão múltiplos de 3, este que esta no enunciado é um exemplo de entrada e o que tem que sair a partir do start "ATG" e Stop no "TAA" ou no "TAG" ou no "TGA".

Comment: Até gostaria de ajudar mas tem muitos erros no seu código e não vou o reescrever do zero e teria que pontuar todos

Comment: Se é intencional, Marcelo, como disse, a abordagem para percorrer a string (indo de três em três pelo `range`) é completamente inválida. Você provavelmente terá que pensar em outra coisa (e, nesse caso, não faremos isso para você aqui, já que não é o objetivo do site).

Comment: Ok! Mesmo assim agradeço a atenção de vocês, vou pensar em alguma outra solução para o exercício.

Comment: Use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) para localizar o indice da primeira ocorrência de `ATG`.

Comment: Obrigado Augusto Vasques, vou ler esse documento e refaze o código.

Comment: Sua lógica está quase correta, só que ao invés do seu `range` começar em zero, deve começar do índice do primeiro codon ATG (que dá pra encontrar usando o método `s.find()` do seu string de entrada, como o @AugustoVasques comentou). Outra coisa, no `range` não há necessidade de calcular o final exato da sequência com `len(s)-len(s)%3`, já que você pega 3 caracteres com slices, e slices nunca dão `IndexError`.

Comment: @jfaccioni ele pode pegar uma fatia `s[s.find("ATG"):]` e a fragmentar em porções de três caracteres com essa função https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496160/137387

Comment: Com as dicas dadas consegui ajeitar um pouco o código usando essa solução: for i in range(s.find('ATG'),s.find('TAA')+1,3): ----- imprime o intervalo desejado, mas o stop pode ocorrer em três casos: 'TAA', 'TAG' e 'TGA'. Gostaria de uma orientação de como fazer isso. Pode ser por aqui ou por indicação de documentação.

Comment: Luiz Felipe, reformulei a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código *funciona*, de modo que irá realizar a contagem a partir do códon `ATG` até o `TAA`.

O problema é que existem três *stop codons* diferentes, e o programa só reconhece o `TAA`. Veja, o problema está onde você cria o intervalo para as iterações:

> ```
> range(s.find('ATG'), s.find('TAA') + 1, 3)
> ```

Você está basicamente criando um intervalo, que incrementa de três em três, do índice da primeira ocorrência da substring `"ATG"` até o índice da primeira ocorrência da substring `"TAA"`.

Vejo dois problemas ao especificar um índice final tal como resultado de `s.find('TAA')`:

1. Você corre o risco de criar um *range* que percorre sobre uma sequência com número inválido de códons (pode haver apenas 5 caracteres entre `ATG` e `TAA`, por exemplo).
2. Você não reconhece os outros dois códons de finalização, `"TAG"` e  `"TGA"`.

Para corrigir esses dois problemas, simplesmente não defina um limite superior no `range`. Simplesmente itere até o comprimento total da string.

Nesse sentido, você pode fazer a verificação do *stop codon* dentro do próprio laço de repetição, de modo a utilizar a declaração `break` para interromper as repetições se tiver encontrado um códon de finalização.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
# Lista de stop codons:
stops = ["TAA", "TAG", "TGA"]

count = {}
for i in range(s.find('ATG'), len(s) + 1, 3):
    codon = s[i: i + 3]
    if codon in count:
        count[codon] += 1
    else:
        count[codon] = 1

    # Se tiver encontrado um stop codon, pare de iterar:
    if codon in stops:
        break
print(count)
```

<sup>Omiti, por brevidade, o restante do código. [Veja funcionando no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/ASVCp1)</sup>

Vale lembrar que, embora funcione com um dicionário comum, o Python oferece outras abordagens melhores para realizar a contagem, tal como a classe [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), disponível no módulo `collections`. Veja:

```
from collections import Counter

stops = ["TAA", "TAG", "TGA"]
count = Counter()
for i in range(seq.find('ATG'), len(seq) + 1, 3):
    codon = seq[i: i + 3]
    count.update([codon])
    if codon in stops:
        break

print(dict(count))
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/3sguVJ)</sup>

Uma outra alternativa é utilizar o `defaultdict(int)`. Embora menos poderoso que o `Counter`, já torna implícita a inicialização de valores `0` no dicionário, o que é feito manualmente no primeiro exemplo de código. Veja mais sobre eles no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19883015/7445826).

Vale observar, por fim, que os dois códigos apresentados nesta resposta imprimirão o resultado da contagem mesmo que um *stop codon* não seja encontrado. Ademais, se o último "códon" dessa string não terminada tiver um ou dois caracteres (e não três, conforme esperado), este também será contabilizado. Para prevenir isso, você pode implementar algum tipo de verificação. Um exemplo é utilizar uma expressão regular, tal como excelentemente demonstrado pela [resposta do Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/513539/69296), de modo a invalidar sequências que fogem do padrão esperado. [Deixo um outro exemplo no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/CUeVPo)

Comment: Luiz Felipe obrigado pela explicação muito esclarecedora só tenho a agradecer a ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Com o auxilio do módulo nativo [re](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#module-re) é possível criar uma [expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185301/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular) que valide a sua sequencia de nucleotídeos e que separe a porção da sequencia contendo os códons. Com um objeto da classe [collection.Counter](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) faça a contagem dos nucleotídeos.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

pattern = r"^[ACGT]*(?<=ATG)(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)(?=TAA|TAG|TGA)[ACGT]*$"

#Define a função contacodon(entrada). O parâmetro regex é inicializado na primeira chamada da função e não deve ser utilizado.
def contacodon(entrada, regex= re.compile(pattern)):
  #Verifica se houver correspondência...
  if m:= re.match(regex, s):
      #se houver correspondência separa o grupo contendo os códons e retorna o dicionário contendo a contagem dos códons.
      cdns = m["codons"]                    
      return dict(Counter([cdns[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(cdns), 3)]))
  else:
      #se não houver correspondência retorna um dicionário vazio.
      return dict()

#s = input("Entre com a seq: \n").upper()
s = "GCGATCGAGATGAGCATCGCATCGCGGACTACCGCGCGCGCGCGCGGGAGATGAGCATCGACGACTCGACTAG"

print(contacodon(s))
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/GATACCA#main.py)</sup>

A expressão regular `^[ACGT]*(?<=ATG)(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)(?=TAA|TAG|TGA)[ACGT]*$` pode ser entendida como:

- `^[ACGT]*` a string deve iniciar com zero ou mais caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.
- `(?<=ATG)` o grupo`(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)` só será capturado se for precedido do start códon `ATG`.
- `(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)` define o grupo de captura `codons` que é composto uma ou mais grupos de três caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.
- `(?=TAA|TAG|TGA)` o grupo`(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)` só será capturado se for sucedido por uma dos stop códons `TAA`, `TAG` ou `TGA`.
- `[ACGT]*$` a string deve terminar com zero ou mais caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.

**EDIT**
Como informado nos comentários, pelo [Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69296/luiz-felipe), o mesmo comportamento também pode ser obtido  da função `contacodon()` usando o seguinte padrão de expressão regular:

```
pattern = r"^[ACGT]*ATG(?P<codons>(?:[ACGT]{3})+)(TAA|TAG|TGA)[ACGT]*$"
```

onde:

- `^[ACGT]*` a string deve iniciar com zero ou mais caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.
- `ATG` corresponda ao start códon `ATG`.
- `(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)` define o grupo de captura `codons` que é composto uma ou mais grupos de três caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.
- `(TAA|TAG|TGA)` corresponda ao stop códons `TAA`, `TAG` ou `TGA`.
- `[ACGT]*$` a string deve terminar com zero ou mais caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.

**EDIT**
Outra sugestão relevante de padrão informada nos comentários, pelo [HKotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo):

```
pattern = "^[ACGT]*?ATG(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)T(?:A[AG]|GA)[ACGT]*$"
```

- `^[ACGT]*?` a string deve iniciar com zero ou mais caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.
- `ATG` corresponda ao start códon `ATG`.
- `(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)` define o grupo de captura `codons` que é composto uma ou mais grupos de três caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.
- `T(?:A[AG]|GA)` corresponda ao stop códons `TAA`, `TAG` ou `TGA`.
- `[ACGT]*$` a string deve terminar com zero ou mais caracteres entre `A`,`C`,`G` ou `T`.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Só fiquei me perguntando se os _lookarounds_ são realmente necessários por aí. Você acha que uma expressão como `^[ACGT]*ATG(?P<codons>(?:[ACGT]{3})+)(TAA|TAG|TGA)[ACGT]*$` já seria suficiente?

Comment: @LuizFelipe, interessante pergunta. Esse padrão de expressão regular apresenta o mesmo comportamento do padrão acima, vou disponibiliza-lo na resposta.

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui e pelo menos para a string da pergunta, sem os *lookarounds* fica um pouco mais rápido (ou "menos lento", mas enfim, se está usando regex, é porque velocidade não é a prioridade :-D - E pra strings pequenas a diferença será irrisória). Enfim, ainda dá pra melhorar um pouco mais: https://regex101.com/r/ZGpfgi/1 - Claro, não fiz muitos testes, não sei se tem alguma sequência bizarra que dê problema (com regex nunca se sabe), mas a princípio acho que não...

Comment: @hkotsubo eu vou subir a sua regex só vou mudar o grupo de captura `(?:[ACGT]{3})+?)` para `(?P<codons>([ACGT]{3})+?)` para que possa se encaixar no exemplo.