# Como formatar strings em python para transformar num array / object / json?

Tags: python

Eu to tentando fazer uma "automação" em selenium usando python, mas minha dúvida em si nem é essa, a parte do selenium consegui terminar já. Minha dúvida é em strings.

Eu queria fazer um object / json com as informações que obtive de uma lista de string, mas eu simplesmente não consigo. A informação da lista está dessa forma:

```
Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1
R$49,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7
R$39,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
Sandman: Prelúdio - Edição Definitiva
R$180,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
Universo DC Por Neil Gaiman
R$104,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
```

Ou seja, a cada 4 linhas é um novo produto, queria deixar algo mais ou menos assim:

```
{
{
"Nome": "Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1"
"Preco": "49,90"
"Carrinho": "Adicionar ao Carrinho"
"Lista": "Adicionar à lista de desejos"
},
{
"Nome": "A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7"
"Preco": "R$39,90"
"Carrinho": "Adicionar ao Carrinho"
"Lista": "Adicionar à lista de desejos"
}
}
```

Mas eu realmente não consegui pensar em uma estratégia para fazer isso. Alguém sabe auxiliar?

Meu código atual:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import time

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get("https://panini.com.br/")
time.sleep(3)
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'search')
search.send_keys('Universo Sandman')
search.submit()
time.sleep(3)

find_sorter = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sorter')
select_sorter = Select(find_sorter)
select_sorter.select_by_visible_text('Mais recentes')

produtos = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'products-grid')
texto_produtos = produtos.text
lista_produtos = texto_produtos.split("\n")

array1 = []
i = 0

for produto in lista_produtos:
if (i < 4):
print(produto)
i = i + 1
if (i == 4):
print("----")
i = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Considerando que você possua o texto:

```py
text = '''Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1
R$49,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7
R$39,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
Sandman: Prelúdio - Edição Definitiva
R$180,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
Universo DC Por Neil Gaiman
R$104,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos'''
```

Comece criando uma lista para separar as linhas utilizando o `split`:

```py
lines = text.split('\n')

# [
#   'Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1',
#   'R$49,90',
#   'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
#   'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
#   'A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7',
#   'R$39,90',
#   'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
#   'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
#   'Sandman: Prelúdio - Edição Definitiva',
#   'R$180,90',
#   'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
#   'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
#   'Universo DC Por Neil Gaiman',
#   'R$104,90',
#   'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
#   'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
# ]
```

Depois percorra essa lista de quatro em quatro elementos:

```py
for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):
   data = lines[i:i+4]
   print(data)

#  ['Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1', 'R$49,90', 'Adicionar ao Carrinho', 'Adicionar à lista de desejos']
#  ['A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7', 'R$39,90', 'Adicionar ao Carrinho', 'Adicionar à lista de desejos']
#  ['Sandman: Prelúdio - Edição Definitiva', 'R$180,90', 'Adicionar ao Carrinho', 'Adicionar à lista de desejos']
#  ['Universo DC Por Neil Gaiman', 'R$104,90', 'Adicionar ao Carrinho', 'Adicionar à lista de desejos']
```

Para melhor legibilidade, desconstrua a sua lista em variáveis melhores nomeadas:

```py
for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):
   data = lines[i:i+4]
   [nome, preco, carrinho, lista] = data
```

Por fim, crie a sua lista de dicionários:

```py
dicionarios = []

for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):
   data = lines[i:i+4]
   [nome, preco, carrinho, lista] = data

   dicionarios.append({
      'Nome': nome,
      'Preco': preco,
      'Carrinho': carrinho,
      'Lista': lista
   })
```

O resultado será:

```
[
 {'Carrinho': 'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
  'Lista': 'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
  'Nome': 'Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1',
  'Preco': 'R$49,90'},
 {'Carrinho': 'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
  'Lista': 'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
  'Nome': 'A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7',
  'Preco': 'R$39,90'},
 {'Carrinho': 'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
  'Lista': 'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
  'Nome': 'Sandman: Prelúdio - Edição Definitiva',
  'Preco': 'R$180,90'},
 {'Carrinho': 'Adicionar ao Carrinho',
  'Lista': 'Adicionar à lista de desejos',
  'Nome': 'Universo DC Por Neil Gaiman',
  'Preco': 'R$104,90'}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução pode ser obtida separando o texto e linhas e agrupa-las em porções de quatro linhas para então as associar com as chaves "Nome", "Preco", "Carrinho", "Lista" , segundo a ordem de entrada, e assim criar uma lista de dicionários que facilmente pode ser serializado como JSON.

Para separar o texto em linhas pode usar o método [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) que retorna uma lista das linhas contidas na string, quebrando a mesma nos limites de cada linha. A documentação desse método fornece uma tabela dos separadores de linhas aceitos.

Para agrupa a lista das linhas em porções de quatro linhas pode ser conseguido usando a função `chunk()` apresentada na resposta a pergunta [Como calcular a média de uma lista de 5 em 5 elementos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496160/137387). `chunk()` é uma [função geradora](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/howto/functional.html#generators) que divida um iterável em porções de tamanho definidos pelo usuário.

Para associar as linhas de cada uma dessas porções com suas respectivas chaves será criado uma tupla `chaves = ("Nome", "Preco", "Carrinho", "Lista")` e a associação será feita com a função embutida [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#zip) que itera sobre vários iteráveis em paralelo, produzindo tuplas com um item de cada um.

Dicionários podem ser criados com constructor [dict()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).
A função embutida [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) aplica uma função a cada item de um [iterável](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).
As expressões [lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#lambda) são usadas para criar funções anônimas.

A serialização o dicionário resultante em uma string JSON pode ser facilmente realizada com o uso do módulo nativo [`json`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/json.html), no caso será usada a função `json.dumps()` com o argumento `False` para o parâmetro `ensure_ascii` permitindo o uso de caracteres [UTF-8](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

```
import json

texto = '''Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1
R$49,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7
R$39,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
Sandman: Prelúdio - Edição Definitiva
R$180,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos
Universo DC Por Neil Gaiman
R$104,90
Adicionar ao Carrinho
Adicionar à lista de desejos'''

#Define a tupla de identificadores de chaves.
chaves = ("Nome", "Preco", "Carrinho", "Lista")                       

#Função geradora apresentada em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496160/137387
def chunk(iteravel, n):
    for i in range(0, len(iteravel), n):
        yield iteravel[i:i+n]
        
# Uma função anônima é aplicada a cada grupo g de 4 linhas associando cada linha a suas respectiva chave e o resultado é convertido em um dicionário.
m = map(lambda g:dict(zip(chaves, g)) , chunk(texto.splitlines(), 4))

#Imprime m
print(json.dumps(list(m), ensure_ascii=False))
#[
#{"Nome": "Universo De Sandman: País Dos Pesadelos Vol. 1", "Preco": "R$49,90", "Carrinho": "Adicionar ao Carrinho", "Lista": "Adicionar à lista de desejos"},
#{"Nome": "A Saga Da Liga Da Justiça Vol. 7", "Preco": "R$39,90", "Carrinho": "Adicionar ao Carrinho", "Lista": "Adicionar à lista de desejos"}, 
#{"Nome": "Sandman: Prelúdio - Edição Definitiva", "Preco": "R$180,90", "Carrinho": "Adicionar ao Carrinho", "Lista": "Adicionar à lista de desejos"},
#{"Nome": "Universo DC Por Neil Gaiman", "Preco": "R$104,90", "Carrinho": "Adicionar ao Carrinho", "Lista": "Adicionar à lista de desejos"}
#]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/WHE9kj)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Se a ideia é continuar com Selenium, existem várias formas de iterar pelas linhas da string. Por exemplo, criando um iterador, e chamando `next` para obter a próxima linha:

```py
# rodar selenium, obter o texto...
texto_produtos = produtos.text

linhas = iter(texto_produtos.split("\n"))
result = []
while True:
    try:
        result.append( { "Nome": next(linhas), "Preco": next(linhas), "Carrinho": next(linhas), "Lista": next(linhas) } )
    except StopIteration:
        break
print(result)
```

Assim, cada chamada de `next` traz a próxima linha, e aí basta colocá-las no dicionário, e adicioná-lo na lista. O chato é que quando um iterador se encerra, ele lança a [exceção `StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration), que precisa ser capturada, e aí sabemos que o *loop* pode ser interrompido (com `break`).

---

No [módulo `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) existe também uma "[receita pronta](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)" para iterar qualquer sequência de N em N elementos:

```py
# rodar selenium, obter o texto...
texto_produtos = produtos.text

from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

result = []
for nome, preco, carrinho, lista in grouper(texto_produtos.split("\n"), 4):
    result.append( { "Nome": nome, "Preco": preco, "Carrinho": carrinho, "Lista": lista } )
print(result)
```

Agora não preciso capturar o `StopIteration`, e repare que no `for` já posso pegar cada um dos 4 elementos separadamente.

---

E também posso usar [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para obter o mesmo resultado:

```py
# rodar selenium, obter o texto...
texto_produtos = produtos.text

from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

result = [ { "Nome": nome, "Preco": preco, "Carrinho": carrinho, "Lista": lista } for nome, preco, carrinho, lista in grouper(texto_produtos.split("\n"), 4)]

print(result)
```

---

E a partir do [**Python 3.12**](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html) (outubro de 2023) é possível usar a [função `itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched), que serve justamente para retornar pedaços de um iterável, um por vez. Neste caso, não precisaria mais da função `grouper`, podendo ser apenas:

```py
# rodar selenium, obter o texto...
texto_produtos = produtos.text

from itertools import batched

result = [ { "Nome": nome, "Preco": preco, "Carrinho": carrinho, "Lista": lista }
           for nome, preco, carrinho, lista in batched(texto_produtos.split("\n"), 4)]
print(result)
```

### Sem Selenium

Para este caso acho que não precisa de Selenium, existem bibliotecas mais apropriadas para web scraping. Vamos ver uma delas: o Beautiful Soup.

Mas antes um detalhe: repare que você está preenchendo o campo de busca e mudando o filtro para "mais recentes". Ao fazer isso, a URL resultante é `https://panini.com.br/catalogsearch/result?q=Universo+Sandman&product_list_order=most_recent`, então você pode acessá-la diretamente, em vez de dar toda essa volta de abrir o browser, digitar, esperar o resultado, etc...

#### Beautiful Soup

Primeiro, [aqui](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tem a documentação e instruções de instalação (`python -m pip install beautifulsoup4`).

Depois, instale também o [módulo `requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) (`python -m pip install requests`) para fazer a requisição HTTP e obter o HTML. Assim é mais direto do que abrir o browser com o Selenium, pois só o que interessa é o conteúdo do HTML (pode usar outros também, existem várias libs para fazer requests HTTP, o importante é que no final você tenha o HTML para repassar para o Beautiful Soup).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

# faz o request para a página e passa o HTML para o Beautiful Soup
url = 'https://panini.com.br/catalogsearch/result?q=Universo+Sandman&product_list_order=most_recent'
with urlopen(url) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read().decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
    # filtra linhas em branco e um texto que não interessa
    lista_produtos = list(filter(lambda s : len(s.strip()) > 0 and s != 'Adicionar para Comparar',
                                 soup.find('div', {'class': 'products-grid'}).get_text(separator='\n').split('\n')))
```

Mas repare que o Beautiful Soup trata um pouco diferente o conteúdo, tanto que o texto vem com muitos espaços e quebras de linha a mais, além de trazer também o texto "Adicionar para Comparar". Então precisei fazer um tratamento adicional para ter uma lista igual a que você obtém com o Selenium.

Depois disso, é só escolher um dos métodos acima para ler a lista de 4 em 4 elementos.

---

Outra opção é, em vez de pegar todo o texto, simplesmente buscar cada elemento que você quer. Dá um pouco mais de trabalho e precisa fuçar a estrutura da página, mas não tem jeito. Pelo menos você vai direto no elemento que tem a informação:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://panini.com.br/catalogsearch/result?q=Universo+Sandman&product_list_order=most_recent'
with urlopen(url) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read().decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
    result = []
    # para cada item retornado
    for product in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-item-details'}):
        # procura o nome do produto
        nome = product.find('a', {'class': 'product-item-link'}).text
        if not nome: # por algum motivo, tinha algum elemento com o nome vazio
            continue # nesse caso, vai para o próximo
        # procura o preço do produto
        preco = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text
        # procura o "carrinho"
        carrinho = product.find('button', {'class': 'tocart'})
        if carrinho is None: # quando não tem estoque, não aparece o carrinho
            carrinho = product.find('div', {'class': 'unavailable'}).text
        else:
            carrinho = carrinho.text
        # procura "adicionar a lista de desejos"
        lista = product.find('a', {'class': 'towishlist'}).find('span').text

        result.append( { "Nome": nome, "Preco": preco, "Carrinho": carrinho, "Lista": lista } )

    print(result)
```

#### Outras opções

Existem várias bibliotecas para web scraping, como o [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/), entre [outras](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+web+scraping+library). Sugiro testá-las para ver como são, pois nesse caso específico, Selenium não me parece a melhor opção. Não há necessidade de abrir um browser, buscar, clicar em tal elemento, quando você pode obter o HTML acessando a URL diretamente (na página que você acessa, não precisa ficar rodando JavaScript para que certos elementos apareçam, etc, situação na qual o Selenium é mais apropriado).